# Is there a way to make global variables in java?

Tags: java

I need to have certain info inside my program which I need to access and modify in between different classes inside different packages. I've tried using a separate class for them but it doesn't work because I need to make a new instance every time I use it in a different class.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class ClassName {
    public static String varName = "this can be used globally;"
}
```

Now can be referenced globally by

`ClassName.varName`

Note: `public` **is important** since a `private` will not be accessible from the outside the class.